# How to fetch data from xml using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I had a  file data.php

```
<div class="content">hello</div>
```

I can fetch data in main file using

main.php

```
<div id="content1"></div>
<script>
$.post("data.php",function(r,s){$("#content1").html(r);});
</script>
```

This script fetches the data from data.php even if i try `data.txt` it also works
but when i convert `data.php` into `data.xml` this does not work

```
<div id="content1"></div>
<script>
$.post("data.xml",function(r,s){$("#content1").html(r);});
</script>
```

what should i do to fetch data from xml file. please help

Comment: Refer this link http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp You wil find a very beautiful explanation .

Comment: Have you tried `$.load` rather than post?

Comment: Check your server settings for the filetype.  jquery will see that it's an xml file and handle it differently.

Comment: @RahulSingh in link javascript ajax is used i want to use jquery

Comment: @freedomn-m  
$.lost also not working, i am doing it at localhost

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jquery ajax then try this method.

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "data.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                    $xml = $(xmlDoc);
                    $title = $xml.find( "title" );
                    $("#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );
                }
            });
```

You need to parseXml data.

Comment: If needed you can refer this link also.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417211/load-xml-file-content-into-div-using-jquery